# Semantic sense of word ‘with’ in sentence

Tags: meaning, grammar, word-usage

The sentence:
“The midwife took 40 roubles for two months' board and attendance, 25 went to get the baby into the foundlings' hospital, and 40 the midwife borrowed to buy a cow with”

What sense does the word “with”(the last word in the sentence) have?

Comment: One of those cases where the preposition has simply been pushed to the end of the sentence.

Comment: The preposition is showing (monetary) agency. I knocked the nail in with a hammer. This is the hammer with which I knocked the nail in. = This is the hammer I knocked the nail in with. // The midwife borrowed 40 roubles with which to buy a cow. = The midwife borrowed 40 roubles to buy a cow with.

Answer (score 0):

Try imagining it as "The borrowed money *with* which the midwife bought the cow: 40 roubles"

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!